# Adding underbrace on $\left(\frac{dB}{dA}\right)^2\right$

Tags: packages, braces

I am trying to add underbrace to `$\left(\frac{dB}{dA}\right)^2\right$`. I have `\underbrace{\left(\frac{dB}{dA}\right)^2\right}_\text{(-)}`.

However, LaTeX is giving me an error. Do I have to install a package for this?

**EDIT:** I have the following packages:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}

\usepackage{natbib}

\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{;}{,}{,}

\usepackage{xr-hyper}

\usepackage[
  colorlinks=true,
  citecolor=blue,
  urlcolor=blue,
  linkcolor=blue
]{hyperref}

\usepackage{bm}

\usepackage{fullpage}

\usepackage{ amssymb }

    \pagestyle{plain}

\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}

\allowdisplaybreaks[4]

% Commenting/debugging
\let\IG\iffalse
\let\ENDIG\fi

%% Shortcuts
\newcommand{\td}[2]{\dfrac{d #1}{d #2}}
\newcommand{\std}[2]{\dfrac{d^2 #1}{d {#2}^2}}
\newcommand{\ctd}[3]{\dfrac{d^2 #1}{d #2 d #3}}

\newcommand{\pd}[2]{\dfrac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
\newcommand{\spd}[2]{\dfrac{\partial^2 #1}{\partial {#2}^2}}
\newcommand{\cpd}[3]{\dfrac{\partial^2 #1}{\partial #2 \partial #3}}

\newcommand{\pdi}[2]{\partial #1/\partial #2}

\newcommand{\LR}{\Leftrightarrow}
\newcommand{\Lg}{\mathcal{L}}
\newcommand{\half}{\tfrac{1}{2}}
\newcommand{\eqp}{\phantom{=}}
\newcommand{\eqs}{\buildrel s \over =}

\begin{document}
\end{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
    \frac{d^2B}{dA^2}=-\frac{1}{\underbrace{(1-p)U'(B)}_\text{(+)}}\left[\underbrace{p U''(A)}_\text{(-)} + \underbrace{(1-p)U''(B)}_\text{(-)}\left(\frac{dB}{dA}\right)^2\right]>0.
```

[image]

I want to add braces to `\left(\frac{dB}{dA}\right)`.

Comment: See if `$\underbrace{\left\{\left(\frac{dB}{dA}\right)^2\right\}_\text{(-)}}$` does what you want.  Please _always_ post a  fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages.

Comment: @PeterGrill I'm not getting a negative sign below with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about a vertical alignment of the `\underbrace`s using a strut:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
  \newcommand{\tempstrut}{\rule[-1.2\baselineskip]{0pt}{1.5\baselineskip}}
  \frac{\mathrm{d}^2B}{\mathrm{d}A^2} =
    - \underbrace{\tempstrut\frac{1}{(1-p)U'(B)}}_{(+)}
    \Bigg[\underbrace{\tempstrut p U''(A)}_{(-)} 
      + \underbrace{\tempstrut (1-p)U''(B)}_{(-)}
      \underbrace{\tempstrut\Bigg(\frac{\mathrm{d}B}{\mathrm{d}A}\Bigg)^2}_{(+)}\Bigg] > 0.
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}


\begin{document}
\[
\frac{d^2B}{dA^2}=-\frac{1}{\underbrace{(1-p)U'(B)}_{\text{(+)}}}\Biggl[\underbrace{p U''(A)}_{\text{(-)}} + \underbrace{(1-p)U''(B)}_{\text{(-)}}
\underbrace{\left(\frac{dB}{dA}\right)^2}_{\text{(+)}}\Biggr]>0.
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The last term is positive though, and do not want a double square on it.